# Redirect Attachment Page to Attachment

Tags: redirect, attachments, media, wp-redirect

I'm trying to change my attachment page to just automatically redirect to the attachment. Here's what I've tried:

Get attachment ID and redirect to that URL:

```
$urlArr = wp_get_attachment_image_src($_GET['attachment_id'], 'full');

if(empty($urlArr))
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url($_GET['attachment_id']);
else
    $url = $urlArr[0];

wp_redirect($url, 301); exit;
```

The redirect to a textual version of the image, I've tried to send extra headers but run into a problem that headers have already been set...

I've searched for it online but only found links where people want to redirect to a certain page, but I'm trying to redirect to the media itself, plugin free. I'm adding the above code directly into `attachment.php` template file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't redirect after content has already been sent to the browser, hook an action before the template is loaded and do your redirect there.

```
function wpa_attachment_redirect(){
    if( is_attachment() ){
        // your code and redirect here
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpa_attachment_redirect' );
```